# Exporting a 3D game object to glb format within unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gltf

I need to export a 3D model to glb format within unity and import them later for other applications.

I've tried packages like gltFast, uniVRM, unityGLTF but they all have some problems while exporting. gltFast seems to work the best. I can succesfully import glb files with it. And when I try to export a game object to glb it seems to work fine and it returns with a success log. But the exported file is corrupted. It can't be opened. And when I try to import the files I exported I get an error like this: ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Missing a name for object member.

Answer (score 2):

The [Prefrontal UnityGLTF](https://github.com/prefrontalcortex/UnityGLTF) works great for me, following these steps:

1. `Package Manager -> + -> Add package from git URL...`

   - `https://github.com/prefrontalcortex/UnityGLTF.git?path=/UnityGLTF/Assets/UnityGLTF`
2. `Assets -> UnityGLTF -> Export Selected as GLB`
3. *Optional* -To check it worked, upload the output to a [web-based GLTF viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)

**NOTE:** This is a more current fork of the unmaintained [Khronos UnityGLTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF)